# Urdu Fonts Display Issue on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS - Seeking Solutions

Tags: fonts, language-support

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and encountering issues with Urdu fonts. In various applications such as browsers and text editors, many Urdu words appear broken and fail to join properly. I've attached a screenshot for reference. Despite my attempts to update fonts and install new Urdu fonts, the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you.[image]